# C# Custom Linq Provider

Tags: c#, linq

I'm developing a custom linq provider following the very helpful article found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx

However, I'm getting stuck when it comes to the 'Not' operator. For example, I am testing with the condition `!a.Name.Equals("2 Test")`. This translates to the lambda expression `{Not(a.Name.Equals("2 Test"))}`.

When I call `ExpressionVisitor.Visit(expression)`, on this expression, my `VisitMethodCall` override is called. However, the `MethodCallExpression` parameter received by that call is missing the Not part of the expression, ie: `{a.Name.Equals("2 Test")}`.

No other overrides are called (I have overriden all that are available). This seems to make it impossible to handle the `Not` part of the expression - however I'm sure that this cannot be the case!

Can anyone shed any light on this for me?
AHA, Ben :)

Comment: Show your `ExpressionVisitor`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `Not` is an unary expression and so the [VisitUnary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.visitunary.aspx) method is called first.

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing, thank you! For some reason VS didn't show it as an available override...